# Tiktok algo simulator

Tags: python

I am making a TikTok algorithm and here is the code it essentially takes the input of the user and determines what rank they are.

```py
import random

share_count = int(input("How many shares did you get on your last tiktok "))
like_count = int(input("How many likes did you get on your last tiktok "))
comment_count = int(input("How many comments did you get on your last tiktok "))
posts = int(input("How many posts do you have on your tiktok page "))

def magic_algorithm(share_count, like_count, comment_count, posts):
    if share_count >= 10000 and like_count > 5000 and comment_count > 200 and posts >25:
        rank = 1 
    elif share_count >= 7000 and like_count > 2000 and comment_count > 60 and posts >25:
        rank = random.randint(2,10)
    elif share_count >= 6000 and like_count > 1500 and comment_count > 50 and posts >25:
        rank = random.randint(11,20)
    elif share_count >= 5000 and like_count > 1300 and comment_count > 33 and posts >20:
        rank = random.randint(21,40)
    elif share_count >= 4000 and like_count > 1000 and comment_count > 25 and posts >15:
        rank = random.randint(41,55)
    elif share_count >= 3000 and like_count > 500 and comment_count > 15 and posts >11:
        rank = random.randint(56,70)
    elif share_count >= 2000 and like_count > 300 and comment_count > 10 and posts >11:
        rank = random.randint(71,80)
    elif share_count >= 1000 and like_count > 150 and comment_count > 10 and posts >11:
        rank = random.randint(81,90)
    elif share_count >= 400 and like_count > 100 and comment_count > 5 and posts >11:
        rank = random.randint(91,95)
    else:
        rank = random.randint(96,100)
    return rank 
print("you rank on the platform is " + magic_algorithm(share_count, like_count, comment_count, posts))
```

but for some reason, I'm encountering an error that states:

```py
print("you rank on the platform is " + magic_algorithm(share_count, like_count, comment_count, posts))
```

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `rank` is an `int` and to concatenate it you need to convert it to `str`.

One way is to :

```
return str(rank)
```

The second method is to use [`f-strings`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/):

```
print(f"you rank on the platform is {magic_algorithm(share_count, like_count, comment_count, posts)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("you rank on the platform is " + str(magic_algorithm(share_count, like_count, comment_count, posts)))
```

This works. You need to convert the `int` to `str`.